# How to set up environment to debug JDK source code (Especially G1 Garbage Collector)

Tags: java, debugging, garbage-collection, gdb

I want to understand the practical working of G1 garbage collector in JDK14 for that I want to set up a debugger in which I can understand the code step by step.
I have configured the jdk14 code with following flags:

```
./configure --with-target-bits=64 --with-debug-level=slowdebug --disable-warnings-as-errors --with-native-debug-symbols=internal
```

and to compile:

```
make all
```

Further, I am trying to debug using gdb with the following command:

```
gdb --args /path/to/java helloWorld
```

gdb gives a segmentation fault.

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff5cb1700 (LWP 272288)]

Thread 2 "java-slowdebug" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff5cb1700 (LWP 272288)]
0x00007fffe100064d in ?? ()
```

Code for helloworld.java.

```
class helloworld{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

But when running the program using /path/to/java helloworld, it works fine.

Please suggest the tools and procedure to set up the debugging environment for JDK14.